# Get last element from several results with cssselector

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

So I have this CSS-selector query that returns several results:

```
div[class=b-folders] span[class=b-folders__folder]
```

[image]

And I want to get only the last one, I tried;

```
div[class=b-folders] span[class=b-folders__folder]:last-of-type
```

But nothing was found.

Comment: What do you mean classic CSS selectors ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Alast-of-type), `:last-child` and other relevant pseudo-classes/selectors check the element's position inside it's parent:

> The `:last-of-type` CSS pseudo-class represents the last sibling with the given element name in the list of children of its parent element.

Instead, *solve it using your selenium language bindings* - get all elements matching the selector and get the last found element. For instance, in Python:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class=b-folders] span[class=b-folders__folder]")[-1]
```

Comment: Any way to reach this last element using the css_selector query without take the last using the results in the code ?

Comment: @davidhol nope, I am afraid this is not possible in this case. Look into XPaths if this is important.

Answer (score 1):

You can have an array list of elements and then select the last element by:

```
List<WebElement> elements= driver.findElements(By.css("css"));

element = elements.get(list.size() - 1);
```